# Can I use html area tag to create different shape text containers?

Tags: html

Is it possible to create text container which is not square/rectangle?

Can I use area tag for this?

Any example snippet will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. All elements are rectangles by defintion. Even the `<area>` tag wouldn't get past that.

Comment: So my only choice is several position absolute elements to curve out the shape?

Comment: @salivan: I'm almost sure there was a library that can do that with JavaScript or jQuery. I don't even remember the name though, so I can't really help you there :(